# Moving files one directory level up fast on filezilla?

Tags: filezilla

I have a website on a test directory folder:

```
www.example.com/tst/
```

I want to move the whole website a directory up to become live (/root folder).

Is there a fast way to do it rather than wait for filezilla to copy every single file which might take hours??

Comment: Log directly into the server and move the files.?

Comment: you mean using cpanel? cant this be done with filezilla